# how to filter table using dropdown on laravel

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

i want to filter my table using dropdown on laravel, it has been works, but when i want to create a new record at the create form, the create form just show the data of the getid function, not create form view.

here my code

```
<form method="GET">
    <div id="sample-table-3">
        <label>Display as Category</label>
        <select name="category_id" id="category_id">
            <option value="0">Show All</option>
            @foreach($categories as $category)
                <option value="{{ $category->id }}">{{ $category->category }}</option>
                    @endforeach
            </select>
    </div>
    </form>
```

here the javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#category_id').on('change', function(e){
            var id_category = e.target.value;
            $.get('{{ url('news')}}/'+id_category, function(data){
                console.log(id_category);
                console.log(data);
                $('#news_data').empty();
                $.each(data, function(index, element){
                    $('#news_data').append("<tr><td>"+element.title+"</td><td>"+element.file+"</td>"+
                    "<td>"+element.content+"</td><td>"+element.like+"</td><td>"+element.view+"</td><td>"+find('.action')+"</td></tr>");
                });
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

and this my controller

```
 public function index(Request $request)
{
    $news = News::paginate(10);
    $categories = Category::all();


    return view('news.news')
    ->with(compact('news'))
    ->with(compact('categories'));
}

public function create()
{
    $news = News::all();

    /* Get Category */
        $categories = Category::all();

    //dd($categories);
    return view('news.create')
    ->with(compact('news'))
    ->with(compact('categories'));
}

public function getid($id_category){
$categories = Category::all();

    if($id_category==0){
        $news = News::all();
    }else{
        $news = News::where('category_id','=',$id_category)->get();
    }
     return $news;
}
```

and this my route

```
Route::get('/news/{id_category}', 'NewsController@getid');
```

Route::group(['middleware' => 'web'], function () {

```
Route::resource('news', 'NewsController', ['except' => ['getid']]);
Route::resource('category', 'CategoryController');
```

});

Comment: Your route `Route::get('/news/{id_category}', 'NewsController@getid');` is probably clashing with the `show` route of `NewsController`. Change it to something like so `Route::get('/news/getid/{id_category}', 'NewsController@getid');`

Comment: thankyou bro, it works :D

Comment: I've converted my comment to an answer. Please accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your route

```
Route::get('/news/{id_category}', 'NewsController@getid');
```

is probably clashing with the `show` route of `NewsController`.

Change it to something like so

```
Route::get('/news/getid/{id_category}', 'NewsController@getid');
```